# Método con un parámetro que si no se pone ninguno pueda devolver algo

Tags: php, sql

Llevo con un ejercicio un par de días y no doy con la solución. Tengo una clar llamada 'gestionLibros' y dentro de ella me piden varios métodos. El primero es uno que establezca conexión con una base de datos que tengo en localhost. La he hecho static para que puedan conectar los métodos siguientes:

```
   static function conexion() {

  $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "Libros");

  if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
     echo "error";
     return NULL;
  } else {
     return $mysqli;
  }
```

}

Y luego el ejercicio me pides esto:

***Añadir a la clase gestionLibros los siguientes métodos:
consultarAutores(autor): Retorna un array asociativo con el id de autor solicitado. Se muestran todos los autores si no se pasa ningún parámetro. NULL si hay algún error.***

Vale, he conseguido que devuelva la fila del id al que pertenece un autor dado pero no veo la forma de hacer que si no meten un parámetro, haga la consulta que muestre toda la tabla. ¿Alguna pista?. Tengo esto en el método:

```
   function consultarAutores($autor) {

  $this->autor = $autor;

  if (isset($autor)) {

     $query = "SELECT * FROM autor WHERE id = $autor;";

     $resultado = mysqli_query($this->conexion(), $query);

     $fila = mysqli_fetch_row($resultado);

     for ($i = 0; $i < count($fila); $i++) {
        echo $fila [$i] . " | ";
     }
  }
```

}

y aquí el index.php

```
      <?php
  require 'gestionLibros.php';

  $prueba = new gestionLibros;
  
  $prueba ->conexion();
  
  $prueba ->consultarAutores(0); // funciona sin problema
  $prueba ->consultarAutores(); // error
  
  ?>
```

He probado una posible solución y me sigue dando error:

```
   function consultarAutores($autor = "") {

  $this->autor = $autor;

  if (isset($autor)) {

     $query = "SELECT * FROM autor WHERE id = $autor;";

     $resultado = mysqli_query($this->conexion(), $query);

     $fila = mysqli_fetch_row($resultado);

     for ($i = 0; $i < count($fila); $i++) {
        echo $fila [$i] . " | ";
     }
  }else{
     $query = "SELECT * FROM autor;";

     $resultado = mysqli_query($this->conexion(), $query);

     $fila = mysqli_fetch_row($resultado);

     for ($i = 0; $i < count($fila); $i++) {
        echo $fila [$i] . " | ";
     }         
  }
```

}

Comment: Pues juraría que ya lo probé y no funcionó. Acabo de probar y sucede este error:
Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function gestionLibros::consultarAutores(), 0 passed

Comment: Nada, ya había probado con parámetros opcionales y nada. Da este error en ese caso:

 Uncaught TypeError: mysqli_fetch_row(): Argument #1 ($result) must be of type mysqli_result, bool given

Comment: Al final de mi pregunta he editado con tu propuesta.

Comment: Nada, no sirve. Creo que null equivale a 0 y entonces toma ese valor, y saca la fila con id = 0. Gracias por intentarlo. Sigo investigando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pues al final he dado con ello. He puesto un parámetro opcional en la función con el valor null y así cuando meto un parámetro me saca solo la fila correspondiente a ese id y cuando no meto nada entra al else y mediante un bucle saca todas las filas:

```
   function consultarAutores($autor = null) {

      $this->autor = $autor;

      if (isset($autor)) {

         $query = "SELECT * FROM autor WHERE id = $autor;";

         $resultado = mysqli_query($this->conexion(), $query);

         $fila = mysqli_fetch_row($resultado);

         for ($i = 0; $i < count($fila); $i++) {
            echo $fila [$i] . " | ";
         }
      }else {

         $query = "SELECT * FROM autor";

         $resultado = mysqli_query($this->conexion(), $query);

         while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_row($resultado)) {

            for ($i = 0; $i < count($fila); $i++) {
               echo $fila [$i] . " | ";
            }
            
            echo "<br>";
         }
      }
   }
```

Comment:  eso era lo que te explicaba que aplicaras en mi último comentario

Comment: exacto, parece ser eso y debía haber otra cosa mal. Estoy empezando en este foro, ¿edito mi respuesta para que la pongas tú? El mérito es tuyo.

Comment: No nada de eso, tienes mi +1 y por favor no olvides marcar tu respuesta como aceptada cuando te sea posible